# jQuery Function loop changing background image crashes firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want a background images to fade in an out.

I have two divs on top of each other with the background set to an image.

In my jQuery I target one div then bring the opacity to zero showing the other one. Then i do the reverse. However, this was working but now for some reason this infinite loop crashes firefox.

What can i do to make it not crash?

```
             $(document).ready(function() {
                function change (){
                  $('#back1').animate({opacity:0}, {duration:3000});
                  $('#back1').delay(1000);
                  $('#back1').animate({opacity:1},  {duration:3000});
                  $('#back1').delay(1000);
                  change();

                }

                change();

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the callback of the function

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you are calling `change()` before the animations have completed, so you are creating a race condition. Animations are asynchronous. Animations have a complete callback you can use.

Try this:

```
function change (){
     $('#back1').animate({opacity:0}, {duration:3000}) 
                .delay(1000)
                .animate({opacity:1},  {duration:3000}, function(){
                      /* use complete callback of final animation to start sequeunce again*/
                      change();
                 });                  

}
```

Comment: Hmnn it does not crash but it only loops one time

Comment: works here  http://jsfiddle.net/gy6CZ/  I added `setTimeout` to compensate for last delay missing

Comment: don't call `$('#back1')` so many times. You are searching the DOM each time to find it..Chain the animatons and/or cache the selector

Comment: I figured it out on your recommendation. 
what you wrote but change this "  
.animate({opacity:1},  3000, function(){
$('#back1').delay(1000)
change();